# Adding Multiple Objects

Tags: java, swing, object

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

Drawing object=new Drawing();  
Timer t=new Timer(1,this);
int score;
ArrayList<Enemy> bombs=new ArrayList<Enemy>();

public Game()
{
    t.start();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(700,600);
    setVisible(true);
    add(object);
    add(new JLabel("Hello"));
    validate();
    createBombs();
}
```

Why am I unable to add both the JLabel and the Object. Only one of them appears. (The JLabel).

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? Can we see the add function ?

Comment: What kind of object is Drawing? Have you been able to show it on any other Control? My best guess is that Drawing gets added without any issues but that it's simply not actually drawing something so it seems that it has not been added.

Comment: Do you know what the default layout manager for a JFrame is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JFrame` has `BorderLayout` as default. In `BorderLayout` `add` method adding the given component to the `CENTER` position.

So:

```
 add(object);
 add(new JLabel("Hello"));
```

with these lines you are adding both item to the `CENTER` position. For example if you add the label to the `SOUTH` position your `object` will be visible.

```
 add(object);
 add(new JLabel("Hello"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

**Edit:**

As @camickr told, you must call `setVisible(true)` after add all of your components. Look at the code below.

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    Drawing object = new Drawing();
    Timer t = new Timer(1, this);
    int score;
    ArrayList<Enemy> bombs = new ArrayList<Enemy>();

    public Game() {
        t.start();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(700, 600);
        add(object);
        add(new JLabel("Hello"));
        validate();
        createBombs();

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried that too but also added BorderLayout.NORTH to my object which I should not have.

Comment: (1+). @Dr.Satti, this is the proper solution although you should be using BorderLayout.PAGE_END. However, you should also be adding the components to the frame BEFORE making the frame visible.

Comment: There is no need for the validate(). Again basic code should be frame.add(...), frame.pack(), frame.setVisible(true).

Comment: I have to use validate()  because the object is a paintComponent. Otherwise the drawing will now show until I adjust the screen size.

Comment: @Dr.Satti, No you do not need the validate(). You have already been told the setVisible() must be the last statement!!! And don't forget to "accept" this answer by clicking on the check mark so people now the problem has been solved because you have been given the simple answer to your question.